# Procedure to import data from a .txt file into the database

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a .txt file with data for import, however this data is defined by substring and not by a delimiter, I am currently doing the following implementation via php to solve the problem:

```
        $handle  = fopen ($destino.'/casa.txt', 'r');
            while(!feof($handle)){
                $linha = fgets($handle);
                $codigo= substr($linha, 0, 10);
                $nome= substr($linha, 10, 2);
                $dt_competencia = substr($linha, 12, 6);

                  if(!$codigo== ""){
                  \DB::insert('insert into casa.moradia(codigo, nome, 
                  dt_competencia)
                    values (?,?,?)', [$codigo, $nome, $dt_competencia]);
                }

       }
            fclose($handle);
```

So I need a procedure to postgres, that reads all files in a folder, open file by file, read row by line, saving via substring in a variable, and then inserts into the database. I am already grateful for any guidance

Comment: I think you would be much better off just adding delimiters using awk or sed (or maybe even php, if that's what you know) and then inserting the data via copy.  It will also be much faster than inserting one row at a time.

Comment: You added the `psql` which indicates the standard command line SQL client for Postgres. But your code looks like some programming language (which one?). Do you want a plain psql solution (e.g. a SQL script) or a program?

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, I've done it in php and it's this code, I'd like to know how I do the same thing as the code, however with pgsql and not with php

Comment: Jeremy, I'll analyze awk, I think it's not possible with sed, some files contain more than 100 thousand lines. Thank you!